# Is it possible to get flask app url without request context?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

It's a URL shortener app. The app structure is like following:
[App structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXkWG.png)

In `forms.py`, I have custom validators: `validate_url()` and `validate_short_url()`
that use `APP_URL`; `APP_URL = "localhost:5000/"`

I'm fine with that running locally, but there is a lot of cases app domain can change:

- Running through docker image;
- Hosting (e.g. on Heroku);
- Changing the port value;

So every time I run this flask app differently I have to change the value of `APP_URL`, which isn't the best practice

All in all, I want to use something like [flask.Request.url_root](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=url_root#flask.Request.url_root) to avoid manual writing again and again

When I just try to use `flask.request` I get the following traceback:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

`forms.py` is posted [here](https://mystb.in/EnvironmentsDescribesDeaf.python)

The app is already hosted on Heroku, here is the link: https://qysqa.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Why url shortener functionality will depend on APP_URL?

Comment: Short URL basically contains that APP_URL inside it. It's f"{APP_URL}/{token}", so if a user pastes this in their browser, they get redirected to the original URL.

I have my app hosted on heroku already, and you gave me an idea to leave a link for it to understand its specific purpose.

Comment: Actually, I can just go ahead with TokenForm, but im still going to need the APP_URL, its length specifically, to set the min-max parameters in [Length()](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/?highlight=length#wtforms.validators.Length)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `flask.request` inside custom validators (`validate_url()` and `validate_short_url()`) where app context gets passed